# Angular 8 dynamic checkbox and dropdown from data from api

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

Here is my stack blitz 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w8g8ng?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

I want to hide the dropdownif the divisions are empty and also default the value of the dropdown to the first one. How can i do this? Please help.

```
<form [formGroup]='newEmployeeForm' class="w-60-l">
  <label [for]="i"  formArrayName="planDivList"
          *ngFor="let plan of newEmployeeForm.controls.planDivList.controls; let i = index"><br>

          <input [name]="i" [id]="i"  type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
          {{planDivList[i].planCode}}

          <label for="inputDiv">Divisions
            <select id="inputDiv" [(ngModel)]="division" (ngModelChange)="errMsg = ''"
              [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" formcontrolName='divCtrl'>
              <option *ngFor="let division of planDivList[i].divisions">{{division.divisionName}}</option>
            </select>
          </label>

        </label>

        <div
          *ngIf="formInvalid && newEmployeeForm.controls.planDivList.hasError('required')">
        At least one plan must be selected
        </div>
</form>
```

Here is my dataset from api that keeps changing

```
 planDivList = [
    { planCode: "B3692", divisions: [] },
    { planCode: "B3693", divisions: [] },
    { planCode: "B67", divisions: [{ divisionCode: "2", divisionName: "Assisted Living " }, { divisionCode: "1", divisionName: "LILC" }] },
    { planCode: "B69", divisions: [{ divisionCode: "3", divisionName: "Four Seasons" }, { divisionCode: "2", divisionName: "Lakeside" }, { divisionCode: "1", divisionName: "Sunrise" }] }

  ];
```

Comment: This code is really confused you are mixing ngForm with reactive form, it's better to revisionate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the dropdown you need to add the *ngIf in the select tag, like this:

`<select *ngIf="planDivList[i].divisions.length > 0" id="inputDiv"...`

And to select the first value of dropdown, you set the value of formControl when you create it, like:

`divCtrl: new FormControl(this.planDivList[0].divisions[0], [Validators.required])`

Comment: hiding worked but not the defaulting .. How do i default a value to the first option in each drop down? Also if i select a value in one drop down the other dropdown value resets to empty.. Here is my code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w8g8ng?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Am i doing it right or is there a different way to achieve my goal?

Comment: You are using the wrong default value, your value of options in HTML is a number `Value="division.divisionCode"`, to fix it I change the HTML to the select tag get the right formControl, `<select id="inputDiv" [formControl]="newEmployeeForm?.controls.divCtrl">
              <option *ngFor="let division of planDivList[i].divisions"  [value]="division.divisionCode">{{division.divisionName}}</option>
            </select>` and in TS you need to add the default value like the divisionCode (1, 2, 3...) `divCtrl: new FormControl(1, [Validators.required])`

Comment: And to handle when the divCtrl values change, you need to add this line `this.newEmployeeForm.controls.divCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => { console.log(value); });`